# kafka-console-producer ignores value serializer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have need to change the value serializer/deserializer in my Kafka setup (for testing purposes I have been using the IntegerSerializer/IntegerDeserializer).  With the JAVA API, it works exactly as expected; however when using the console tools, it doesn't seem to work correctly.

All of the trouble shooting that I have done has lead me to one conclusion: It appears that the kafka-console-producer is ignoring the Serializer options.  I have tried `--property value.serializer` and `--producer-property value.serializer` and `--value-serializer` and setting it in a configuration with the `--producer.config` argument.

Its not just failing to Serialize the data as an integer, it doesn't even care if I enter nonsense as the argument value.  With the kafka-console-consumer (which works perfectly with its IntegerDeserializer) if I enter `--value-deserializer not.a.real.class` it will throw a class not found exception; however `--value-serializer not.a.real.class` on the kafka-console-producer, does nothing.

Setting these values on the producer in the JAVA API, works perfectly (and will throw an exception if I enter nonsense as the serializer class) but not when using the kafka-console-producer.

This is an example of one of the ways I tried to run the console producer:

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list IPADDRESS:9092 --topic TOPIC --property value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer
```

And the related consumer:

```
kafka-console-consumer --bootstrap-server IPADDRESS:9092 --topic TOPIC  --property value.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerDeserializer
```

Has anyone managed to get this working with the command line tools?  Is there something obvious that I am missing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-2526) in the console producer. you can work around it by passing the `--old-producer` option to the tool.

Comment: I tried to Google this and couldn't find examples of it working.  That JIRA is from 2015, thats disappointing.  Thank you.

Comment: Does this work-around actually work? This still did not work for me: `kafka-console-producer --broker-list IPADDRESS:9092 --topic TOPIC --producer-property value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer`.

Comment: `$ ... --old-producer`
old-producer is not a recognized option

Comment: This known bug is a rather simple fix. Its incredible that it has had a PR after 7 years!